# Variable value shows as null

Tags: java, interface

variable `recUsername` is assigned with a value passed by another controller. But after initialization when `recUsername` is printed inside `BtnClicked` method, it prints `null`. why?

```
public class nextSceneController implements Initializable {
    private String recUsername;
    public void transferMessage(String message){
        recUsername = message;
    }
    @FXML
    private Button Btn;

    @FXML
    void BtnClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(recUsername);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        System.out.println(recUsername);
    }
}
```

This is MenuController.java which is linked to menu.fxml

```
public class MenuController {
    public MenuController() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    }
    String orderRefNo = Key_Generator.getReferenceKey();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("orderList.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    OrderListController orderListController = loader.getController();
    orderListController.transferMessage(orderRefNo);
    Stage orderListStage = new Stage();
    orderListStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    orderListStage.show();
}
```

This is OrderListController which is linked to orderList.fxml

```
public class OrderListController implements Initializable {
    public OrderListController() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    }
    private String orderRefNoRec;
    public void transferMessage(String message){
        orderRefNoRec = message;
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try{
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `FoodName`, `Quantity`, `Price` FROM `orders` WHERE OrderRefNo='"+orderRefNoRec+"'");
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()){
                observableList.add(new orderListTableModel(resultSet.getString("FoodName"), resultSet.getString("Quantity"),
                        resultSet.getString("Price")));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        food_OrderListTableModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("foodName"));
        quantity_OrderListTableModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("qty"));
        price_OrderListTableModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

        orderListTableModel.setItems(null);
        orderListTableModel.setItems(observableList);
    }
}
```

Comment: initialize is called before transferMessage

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling these methods? I suspect ByteHamster is correct.

Comment: Yes I think he is correct. Btw what code you are asking.

Comment: @ByteHamster Hi, Is there a way to get the variable value at initialization.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you need to illustrate out your program flow, to know when you are able to call up the set variable.

Below an illustration on where it probably goes wrong(Can't say for certain as I don't have access to the full code, but this is an oversimplification of the most likely issue at hand):

[image: diagram]

- Your main scene controller creates a new nextScene.
- The business logic then calls initialize to pass along all necessary resources etc...
- You call print here, but `transferMessage` hasn't been called yet at this point, so the `recUserMessage` variable is still null.
- You then probably call `transferMessage`, which sets the variable, but printing is then never called.

When you come across such a problem in the future, where something doesn't do what you think it should do, draw it out, step by step what you think is happening to pin point where things should happen and where your expectations should be adapted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing your the knowledge in detailed way. My main purpose was in my application I have to populate a tableview in a controller. The tableview get data from DB with sql for the sql I have to provide a variable string value which is generated in the previous scenes controller and passed into this controller. Any other method to do this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to post how you create this nextSceneController code for me to be able to help with this. So the "previous controller".

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question with my main program. Please review it. Thanks.